# How can enormous giants hide their existence in a modern city?

Tags: society, technology, mythical-creatures, humanoid

Meet the Artarons, a group of giants of unknown origin. This troop consists of 15 humongous human-like giants, they have been living isolated in the woods to keep themselves secluded from the modern world, and are currently striving to secretly sneak and live in a modern city.

These giants stood at a towering 16'5"(5m) height making it extremely difficult for them to go unrecognizable in public.  They are just like humans, they can talk, they need food, entertainment, they wear clothes, and so on. They can't directly go out to public since they will, without a doubt, be hunted down for numerous reasons

Each of them have quite an amount of money, say, the average middle age citizen net worth, they are also up to date with technology, which gives them a huge advantage. However, there are still many obstacles that are still yet to be dealt by these giants in order to secrete their existence, namely,

- Obtaining foods; they can't easily go out to restaurants or supermarkets
- Getting a shelter; building gigantic houses will cause them to be easily spotted
- Acquiring accessories and daily resources; daily accessories like toothbrushes need to be made extra large
- Purchasing clothes; clothes will also have come in an extra large size
- Transportation; They won't fit into normal vehicles
- Wealth does not last forever; Preserving money and balancing cashflow is a must

Considering all these challenges and many more, is it possible for this group of giant to live a hidden life in our modern city? If so, how would they manage to carry this out?

Comment: How have they lived undetected up until this point?  Are they allowed to bring any humans in on their secret?  How much room do they need on a day-to-day basis?  How much is "quite an amount" of money?  Is there a particular modern city in mind - prices vary considerably.  Do they have any marketable skills that they can use without revealing themselves (eg software programming, IT support)?

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Thank you for the questions :) Ive added the details to the post. For the particular city name,  any city shouldnt be a problem since their wealth is adjusted based on the average citizen wealth of that city/area

Comment: Do they have human assistants who can keep a secret?

Comment: I have no idea on how they currently would do it, but the first thing that popped into my mind was that they were responsible for the preternatural degree of fog in Victorian London - as in the fog hid them while they walked around.

Comment: @Alexander They keep themselves secluded from any human, hiring human assistants is possible but that is quite risky.

Comment: "They keep themselves secluded from any human" - having at least a few regular humans to assist is crucial for any of the solutions to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Buy a group of warehouses, all with sufficiently high ceilings.

Living space, workshops, and office space would be one or two buildings in the center of the complex. This keeps our tall friends away from the periphery.

Big people need big amounts of food. Trucks delivering food to warehouses aren't suspicious. The same goes for fabric and other  components needed to produce super-sized items.

Those giant sized workshops in the central area allow for large sized tailoring as well as wood and metal working.

Obviously, they would need some human employees who aren't too likely to call the government or, far worse, the tabloid press. With the correct warehouse arrangement, perimeter security guards and those in the outermost building wouldn't need to know about any big secrets, which reduces the number of trustworthy humans needed.

If any of them need to leave the warehiuse complex, a large cargo truck could carry one or two either semi-reclined or fully reclined.

Where the large people got large amounts of money from isn't revealed in the question (at least not yet), nor are whatever special skills they might have to enable them to get a big paycheck.

If they weren't a secret, the city police and fire departments would love them. Since they are a secret, maybe there's some sort of online work they could do.

Comment: +1 Warehouses! can't believe that didn't occur to me!

Comment: In the modern setting and if its a country modeled after the US where jounalists do not require a license, especially with the advent of internet, THEY can be the tabloid press and control fringe narratives and be the first to steer away rumors of their existence.

Comment: @BeyondDisbelief - Good idea! After all, giants have a natural advantage telling tall tales. 

Comment: Seems like a waste of a giant's natural physical advantages to just have them work on the internet.  Unless you want to mess with people by having them be YouTube/TikTok celebrities, but on an over-sized set so you can't tell they're larger than normal until a human walks on camera, and even then you can just pretend it's special effects...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I fully agree, but it's not easy to keep them secret if they are replacing the forklifts at Costco or Sam's Club. If they reveal themselves and don't end up locked away in Area 51, there are all sorts of things they could do.

Answer (score 7):

For going out in public, while they wouldn't exactly go *unnoticed* an option would be to hide in plain sight by pretending to be giant puppets ala [Little Amal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Amal)

> Obtaining foods; they can't easily go out to restaurants or supermarkets

Delivery is very much a thing.

> Getting a shelter; building gigantic houses will cause them to be easily spotted

You mention that they have a certain amount of wealth - buying multiple storey buildings and effectively removing the alternating floors would give them double-height spaces. Construction crews could be hired to do the modifications without knowing who they were for.

> Transportation; They won't fit into normal vehicles

It wouldn't be particularly pleasant I suppose but they could easily travel long distances by lying down in shipping container and have that pulled by a truck. They could probably quite easily fit one out with cushioning and even mount entertainment such as a TV. It could even be used for international travel via a ship.

> Acquiring accessories and daily resources; daily accessories like toothbrushes need to be made extra large

Many things could be simply re-purposed items from the "little folk" [Toothbrush?](https://www.knivesandtools.co.uk/en/pt/-lodge-cleaning-brush-scrbrsh.htm)

> Purchasing clothes; clothes will also have come in an extra large size

I suspect the easiest way is either going to be through having giants who can do bit of clothesmaking (and just purchasing the material components), also it wouldn't be ridiculous for someone to special order some clothes for the "giant puppet".

> Wealth does not last forever; Preserving money and balancing cashflow is a must

Without knowing how they got their money in the first place is there any reason they can't just do more of that? If that isn't an option there's lots of occupations that particularly in the modern world can be done 100% remotely; writing, artwork, stock investing/trading, heck software development!

The need for decent internet access even makes something of an argument for why they might live in a city (and put up with the inconvenience of sneaking around) in the first place.

Most of the logistics of this will go a lot smoother if there's at least one normal sized human who can be the "face" of any in-person interactions they require, or if the group requires *absolute* secrecy how about a young giant or a "short" one who is within the bounds of human-height, say about 7ft?

Comment: Amazing answer, I love your last point which is to send younger giants who have a plausible human height to go out and be the face for the other giants.

Comment: Making clothes: basic stuff isn't hard (fancy or smart things are another matter but within a hobbyist range of skills), but a typical human-scale sewing machine would be too fiddly to use.  Older, simpler, more industrial machines might be OK with fingers 2-3x as big as they were built for; the latter would also be able to handle the bigger pieces of fabric better.

Answer (score 2):

### They will live and work in an amusement/theme park

They will act like robots/animatronics, possibly in a section with fairytale theme so giants can blend in (inside some costumes, wearing masks etc.) or they could be even controlling giant dinosaur models in a section with dinosaur theme. It would be better that the park is a big one like Disneyland or Universal Studios.

[image] [image]

They have to make an unbreakable agreement/contract with the park manager so he will be the only person they can trust (possibly with some security staff included). The park manager will arrange things in a way that they can't be discovered.

He will supply the stuff they need. The park manager can make the design/creative team create suitable stuff that giants need also. He will pay giants for their service as well. (Giants can pay him to buy stuff or some certain amount is deducted from the paycheck for the supplies.)

Visitors and all other employees will be in the park during the daytime. Giants will be free after they leave. Amusement parks usually have giant structures and cave-like places also that they can stay and sleep in.

They can be transported (possibly in their costumes in case there are checkpoints) in an 18-wheeler.